# setting custom routes only form some pages in asp.net web forms

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes, global-asax

I made a website using asp.net webforms. It uses the default route which is url friendly. Can I set a custom route for some pages by assigning it to global.asax without affecting all other pages route?

Comment: [This](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1014851/URL-Re-Writing-with-Global-asax) can help you.

Comment: @M.Y.Mnu But I want only page which I define in golbal asax should have custom routing. If I do this then it will disable default routing as well.

Answer (score 0):

**By default MVC uses the conventional routing which uses something of this sort.**

```
routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Which translates to `http://localhost:9999/<controllerName>/<ActionName>/<OptionalIDs>`

But if you want custom routes its possible in ASP.NET MVC 5 this feature is called **Attribute Routing**, if you are using Visual Studio 2015 or above.

For example:

Adding the following line to your global.asax.cs file will enable attribute routing in your MVC 5 application:
`routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();`

**This will be rendered as http://localhost:9999**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route(Name = "HomeView")]
public ActionResult Index()
{
  return View();
}
```

**This will be rendered as http://localhost:9999/Login**

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("~/Login", Name = "LoginGET")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
   return View();
}
```

**In your view you can use the `Html.BeginRouteForm("<RouteName>", FormMethod.Post)` helper method for handling routes.**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("~/Login", Name = "LoginPOST")]
public ActionResult Login(FormCollection UserCredentials)
{
   //do stuff
   return RedirectToRoute("HomeView");
}
```

**For referring MVC Actions via Routes in _layout.html you can use:**

```
Html.RouteLink("Link text that you want to display in the view", "<RouteName>");
```

For More information you can always check MSDN [**Attribute Routing**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2013/10/17/attribute-routing-in-asp-net-mvc-5/).

Comment: Thanks for this but I am looking solution for web forms not MVC